# Did the Prophet say letting scholars decide what is lawful and unlawful is taking other Gods beside Allah?

Tags: source-identification

Maududi commented:

> According to a Tradition, when Hadrat `Adi bin Hatim, who was formerly a Christian, came to the Holy Prophet with the intention of understanding Islam, he asked several questions in order to remove his doubts. One of these was: "This verse accuses us of taking our scholars and monks as our lords. What is its real meaning, sir? For we do not take them as our fords." As a reply to this, the Holy Prophet put him a counter-question: "Is it not a fact that you accept as unlawful what they declare to be unlawful, and lawful what they declare to be lawful?" 'Adi confessed, "Yes, sir, it is so." The Holy Prophet replied, "This amounts to making them your lords."
> (9.30)

Does anyone know the source for this hadith

Thank you

Comment: See also [What is the source and health of the priest worship hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/856/what-is-the-source-and-health-of-the-priest-worship-hadith) and [A more detailed hadith about 9:31](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61214/a-more-detailed-hadith-about-931?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The hadith is not about scholars but priests.

Answer (score 1):

This is the source:

> Narrated 'Adi bin Hatim: "I came to the Prophet (ﷺ) while I had a cross of gold around my neck. He said: 'O 'Adi! Remove this idol from yourself!' And I heard him reciting from Surah Bara'ah: They took their rabbis and monks as lords besides Allah (9: 31). He said: 'As for them, they did not worship them, but when they made something lawful for them, they considered it lawful, and when they made something unlawful for them, they considered it unlawful.'"
>
> Jami` at-Tirmidhi 3095
>
> Chapter 10: Regarding Surat At-Tawbah, Book 47: Chapters on Tafsir
>
> Grade: Da'if (Darussalam)

https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3095

Comment: thank you so much do you know a Sahih version of this ?

Comment: There is probably not a sahih version of it, it is most likely the only one. I saw in [some places](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2012/04/16/tawhid-yahud-nasarah-gods/) which says the Shiekh Al-Albani apparently graded it hasan. But I tried to find another version of it, couldn't find it in the internet in English. Yet I am not 100% sure.

Comment: [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111866/the-status-of-ruling-by-that-which-allaah-has-revealed-in-islam) used this hadith in their fatwa, but they didn't give the grade of it. So probably what I read regarding Shiekh Al-Albani grading it hasan is true.